# Example of adding a visualforce component in a lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning

Could someone give me an example of adding a visualforce component in a lightning component?

Specifically, I would like to use [apex:relatedList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) in my custom lightning component.

I really can find nothing on it in the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** use `apex:relatedList` on a Lighting Component. And that's just because its not an Aura component but a Visualforce. Remember, both are different frameworks and you cannot use components interchangeably but only expose using embedded Visualforce pages or invoke a LC from a Visualforce page.

Even if you had an `apex:relatedList` say on a Visualforce page, that you wanted to use in LEX, you won't be able to do so. Refer to this excerpt from [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_known_issues):

> **apex:relatedList and Blacklisted Related Lists**
>
> There are a number of related lists that aren’t supported in Lightning Experience. These related lists are “blacklisted,” which means they are explicitly prevented from being used. As you might expect, these same related lists are blacklisted in Visualforce with the  tag.

Comment: Does that mean that I won\`t be able to see an `apex:relatedList` on my custom lightning component whatever I do?

Comment: Yes, that’s what the documentation mentions. You may just need to resort to create a custom component if you want to use anything around related lists.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing is this is the only way how I can embed a VF page into my lightning component: `<iframe src="{! '/apex/YourPageName'}" width="100%" height="500px;" frameBorder="0"/>`?

Comment: That's how I have known so far.

Comment: What will happen if I will put the `apex:relatedList` in VF page and then add the page to my lightning component?

Comment: I haven't tried it so not sure. I would though think it just doesn't show up or throws a run-time error.

Comment: Could you answer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230871/where-can-i-get-the-url-for-adding-a-vf-page-through-iframe-to-a-custom-lightnin) question, please?

Comment: I tested this out and `apex:relatedList` just does not get displayed in Lightning Experience.