# Where can I get the URL for adding a VF page through iframe to a custom lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, url, iframe

Where can I get the URL for adding a VF page through `iframe` to a custom lightning component?

1 I create a VF page.

2 I know that I can display it in lightning using the following approach

`<iframe src="{!'myURL'}" width="100%" height="300px;" frameBorder="0"/>`

Where can I get `myURL`?

Comment: I have answered a previous question about this you could refer that. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/what-url-to-specify-in-a-visualforce-embeded-in-a-lightning-component-in-communi/222181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide the `src` here. It actually is the absolute url to your VF page along with your instance url.

So let's say you have a VF page named `myVFPage`, and that your instance URL is say `https://your-subdomain.my.salesforce.com`, then your code should look like as below:

```
<iframe src="https://your-subdomain.my.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage" width="100%" height="300px;" frameBorder="0"/>
```

And to add more details to this, you may like to actually maintain a variable on your component which gets populated during the `init` of your component which gets populated with your instance URL. You will need to make a server trip here though. But with this approach, you don't have to hard-code the URL whenever you deploy the code to other sandboxes. And that you use that variable to construct the URL. Something as below:

```
<iframe src="{!v.baseURL + '/apex/myVFPage'" width="100%" height="300px;" frameBorder="0"/>
```