# Get relative path to Visualforce page via Lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have an iframe in a Lightning component that points to a Visualforce page, but I don't know what the relative path is in Salesforce from Lightning components to Visualforce pages. I currently have this set-up so it's relative to my code in SFDX project:

```
  <iframe src="../../pages/ReCaptcha.page" height="110px" width="304px" frameborder="0" style="border: 0;" />
```

Of course, that's not the actual location of the Visualforce page in Salesforce. How can I get that?

Comment: It has to be absolute URL of your VF page. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230873/54851).

Comment: I believe it can be a host-relative URL like "/apex/Page".